# Using $rootScope to call a function on callback

Tags: angularjs, broadcast, servicenow, angularjs-rootscope

Our team is building a Service Portal page in ServiceNow and have a widget that opens a Material modal window via ng-click:

```
<md-button id="small-btn" class=" btn1" ng-click="showAdvanced($event)" >   
     <md-icon ng-if="!data.sysID" ng-style="{'background-color':'#F44336'}" class="circle-border md-60">assignment</md-icon>
     <md-icon ng-if="data.sysID" ng-style="{'background-color':'#4CAF50'}" class="circle-border md-60">assignment_turned_in</md-icon>
</md-button>
```

The ng-click function looks like this:

```
$scope.showAdvanced = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: 'material-modal',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose:true,
preserveScope: true,
focusOnOpen: false,
scope:$scope
    })
//Broadcast this function
$rootScope.$broadcast();
  };
```

In another widget, I have and IntroJS Tour and am trying to implement an oncomplete callback that opens the modal window once the tour is finished:

```
intro.oncomplete(function() {
     //run the showAdvanced() function that opens the modal window from above
     $rootScope.$on()
});
```

Is $rootScope the best way to accomplish this?  If so, can someone provide some suggestions on syntax?  I've tried to follow some examples on other stackoverflow questions, but can't seem to get it to work.  Thanks!

Comment: Broadcasting requires an event name: `$rootScope.$broadcast('event-name');` and `$rootScope.$on('event-name', listenerFunction);`. For more information, see [AngularJS $rootScope.$broadcast API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast).

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "can't seem to get it to work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.